# Regex Pattren issue in NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, regex

I am trying to convert my PHP code into NodeJS

I am getting `null` with following NodeJS attempt

```
matches = data.match(/@objid="(.*?)" href="(.*?)" data-autoplay="(.*?)"@si/);
```

But in PHP, The following line working fine for me

```
preg_match_all('@objid="(.*?)" href="(.*?)" data-autoplay="(.*?)"@si', $content, $adress_link);
```

Sample Data

```
data-objid="293001169457" href="https://m.ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=moviePlaybackRedirect&amp;st.sig=f74e88c3bb4366f8d16afedd42c5d8e56808f175&amp;st.mq=2&amp;st.mvid=293001169457&amp;st.ip=182.185.185.173&amp;st.dla=on&amp;st.exp=1542464401749&amp;st.hls=off&amp;_prevCmd=movieLayer&amp;tkn=6519" data-autoplay="1"><img src="//pimg.mycdn.me/getImage?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvdp.mycdn.me%2FgetImage%3Fid%3D142641728249%26idx%3D8%26thumbType%3D32%26f%3D1&amp;type=VIDEO_S_368&amp;signatureToken=gO17aWVQ5f69KKvIJCtsDQ" alt="Video" class="vdo thumb"/><div class="vdo playb"></div><div class="vd_tmr">2:18:57</div></a><div class="vdospinner"></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="mvtxt card"><div class="a-menu toggle"><input class="a-menu_control tgl-cbox" type="checkbox" hidden="hidden" checked="checked" autocomplete="off" id="m-1542291601750-1"></input><div class="a-menu_content_w tgl-toggled" aria-hidden="true"
```

Comment: `@` are regex delimiters, in JS, you can only use `/`. And remove `s` flag and replace each `.*?` with `[^"]*`. And add `g` modifier to match all occurrences.

Comment: What about `si` flags?

Comment: You may still keep `i` flag. If you need to access groups, you can't use `String#match(/r/g)`, you need to run `RegExp#exec` in a loop.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `/objid="([^"]*)" href="([^"]*)" data-autoplay="([^"]*)"/gi` this is still not working for me, please correct me

Comment: You have not mentioned anything about how it should work. And see my previous comment.

Comment: Provide a sample string, and expected output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have include sample data in my question now :)

Comment: And what is the expected result? An array containing 3 values? Are you expecting one match or more than 1? These are important details, your question is still unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 1 match between `href="` & `"`

Comment: Then why do you have 3 capturing groups in the original pattern?

Comment: Actually need only value between `href` quotes

Comment: Something like `/objid="[^"]*"\s+href="([^"]*)"\s+data-autoplay=/i.exec(string)[1]`?

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/objid="[^"]*"\s+href="([^"]*)"\s+data-autoplay=/i
```

and grab Group 1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nB5VGE/1).

**Details**

- `objid="` - literal text
- `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `href="` - literal text
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `data-autoplay=` - literal text.

JS demo:

```js
var s = 'data-objid="293001169457" href="https://m.ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=moviePlaybackRedirect&amp;st.sig=f74e88c3bb4366f8d16afedd42c5d8e56808f175&amp;st.mq=2&amp;st.mvid=293001169457&amp;st.ip=182.185.185.173&amp;st.dla=on&amp;st.exp=1542464401749&amp;st.hls=off&amp;_prevCmd=movieLayer&amp;tkn=6519" data-autoplay="1"><img src="//pimg.mycdn.me/getImage?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvdp.mycdn.me%2FgetImage%3Fid%3D142641728249%26idx%3D8%26thumbType%3D32%26f%3D1&amp;type=VIDEO_S_368&amp;signatureToken=gO17aWVQ5f69KKvIJCtsDQ" alt="Video" class="vdo thumb"/><div class="vdo playb"></div><div class="vd_tmr">2:18:57</div></a><div class="vdospinner"></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="mvtxt card"><div class="a-menu toggle"><input class="a-menu_control tgl-cbox" type="checkbox" hidden="hidden" checked="checked" autocomplete="off" id="m-1542291601750-1"></input><div class="a-menu_content_w tgl-toggled" aria-hidden="true"';
var rx = /objid="[^"]*"\s+href="([^"]*)"\s+data-autoplay=/i;
var match = rx.exec(s);
if (match) {
   console.log(match[1]);
}
```